# update Progress not closing while streaming back csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an update panel and inside that, i have placed many controls like ajax updateprogress, radio buttons and FileUpload control.
I have two buttons at the end, one which saves the data and other which generates xml data.

While Genearting xml, i am streaming back to the screen in the following code,

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filePath);
 Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
 Response.End();
```

At this point, the update progress image is not getting closed.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

because the response is ending when the file is sent to the client.
you need to do it in new page.

in your page, replace your code in:

```
Session["filePath"] = filePath;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'file.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
```

the new page (called "file.aspx"):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  Session["filePath"].ToString());
     Response.TransmitFile(Session["filePath"].ToString());
     Response.End();
}
```

Comment: This will redirect to new page and the new page will have the streamed content,but the main page will still show the update progress to be rotating.I don't want that.

Comment: what you describing should not happen, the update progress should be end.

Comment: :Ya,thats what I am also sayng,I want the Update progress to be end and at the same time,it has to stream back the csv data.

Comment: so put in the session the data that you want to stream back, and in the same onclick event tell the update progress to take it